# For loop to display the first 30 powers of 2 in C?

Tags: c

I wanted to print the power of 2 until certain numbers? like in here I wanted to print first 30 power of 2. Below my code! but I don't know the solution!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i;

    //long pot = 1;

    for(i=0; i<=32; i=i*2) {

        printf("%d ", i);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Given you initialize `i` to `0`, any subsequent multiplication will result in.. what? And of course the comparison with 32 is incorrect, as your `i` is *supposed* to hold the result.

Comment: You're using i for two purposes here: it's your loop index and your value, so you'll only go through the loop 5 times.

Comment: Debugger, printf of 'i', stuff like that.  Writing code is easy,. testing and debugging is hard, and that is what you must get better at.

Answer (score 1):

You start `i` at 0, then you perform `i=i*2` on each iteration.  This will always result in 0 because you're multiplying by 0.

You want to start with 1.  Then your multiplications will work.  Also, you would need `i` to stop at 2<sup>30</sup> instead of 32.

There is another way to do this however.  You can take advantage of the fact that multiplying by 2 is the same as shifting left by 1:

```
for(i=0; i<30; i++) {
    printf("%d ", 1 << i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> For loop to display the first 30 powers of 2 in C?

Do your processing (multiplication) inside the loop. This is the most common approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define POWER_UP_TO   30

int main(void) {

    long long int value = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < POWER_UP_TO; i++) {  // will loop POWER_UP_TO times

        printf("2^%d = %lld\n", i, value);
        value = value * 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2^0 = 1                                                                                                                                       
2^1 = 2                                                                                                                                       
2^2 = 4                                                                                                                                       
2^3 = 8                                                                                                                                       
2^4 = 16                                                                                                                                      
2^5 = 32                                                                                                                                      
2^6 = 64                                                                                                                                      
2^7 = 128                                                                                                                                     
2^8 = 256                                                                                                                                     
2^9 = 512                                                                                                                                     
2^10 = 1024                                                                                                                                   
2^11 = 2048                                                                                                                                   
2^12 = 4096                                                                                                                                   
2^13 = 8192                                                                                                                                   
2^14 = 16384                                                                                                                                  
2^15 = 32768                                                                                                                                  
2^16 = 65536                                                                                                                                  
2^17 = 131072                                                                                                                                 
2^18 = 262144                                                                                                                                 
2^19 = 524288                                                                                                                                 
2^20 = 1048576                                                                                                                                
2^21 = 2097152                                                                                                                                
2^22 = 4194304                                                                                                                                
2^23 = 8388608                                                                                                                                
2^24 = 16777216                                                                                                                               
2^25 = 33554432                                                                                                                               
2^26 = 67108864                                                                                                                               
2^27 = 134217728                                                                                                                              
2^28 = 268435456                                                                                                                              
2^29 = 536870912
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long value = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i += 1) {
        printf("%ld\n", value);
        value *= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long int n = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("%lld\n", n);
        n = n*2;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```